# How do you create a namespace in AWS CloudWtach

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create a namespace for metric reporting in AWS CloudWatch but can't find any documentation or interface that allows me to specifically do this so I can then later create metrics and dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The namespace is automatically created when you insert custom metrics. Caveat, we've only tried a naming convention that mirrors AWS, e.g. `Type/Service`.

http://aws-cloudwatch.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip

```
my %params = ();
$params{'Input'} = {};
my $input_ref = $params{'Input'}; 
$input_ref->{'Namespace'} = "System/Linux";
```